# Call function of parent and child using serial queue in swift3

Tags: ios, swift

I have two classes **ParentViewController** and **ChildViewController** (which is derived from **ParentViewController**)

The **ChildViewController** have a function called **fetchAuthIdFromServer()** which calls an api and get a value say **authid** from the server and save it in the local DB, and for each call the **authid** value will be different.

The **ParentViewController** have a function called **getAuthIdFromLocal()** which fetch the **authid** value from local db.

I am calling the **fetchAuthIdFromServer()** in **viewWillAppear** and **getAuthIdFromLocal()** in **viewDidAppear**.

The functions are called just fine, as first calls **fetchAuthIdFromServer()** and then **getAuthIdFromLocal()**.

The main problem is that, because of **fetchAuthIdFromServer()** have a server call, the **getAuthIdFromLocal()** is completed before **fetchAuthIdFromServer()** and get the previous value of **authid** (not the latest).

I want to call the **getAuthIdFromLocal()** after the completion of **fetchAuthIdFromServer()**.

Is this possible using serial queue, please note that **they are in different classes and can't call the two functions in the same class**.Also for some reasons, I can't call **getAuthIdFromLocal()** inside the completion block of **fetchAuthIdFromServer()**.

Please tell me, can I use serial queue here, means add these two functions in a serial queue and run that queue in any way.

Comment: you can just trigger a Notification when one task completes and based on observing that notification, trigger second api.

Comment: Parent and Child controlled are in inheritance or they are Container View Controller

Comment: ChildViewController inherited from ParentViewController

Comment: you can modify the ** fetchAuthIdFromServer()** to get a function as argument  a**function** or **closure**. Then execute that function or closure after saving to local DB.
if you use a function then you can pass the ** getAuthIdFromLocal**, else if you use a closure then you can call the **getAuthIdFromLocal** in that closure

Answer (score 1):

You have to call **getAuthIdFromLocal()** method in **ChildViewController** after receiving the response from the server.

Simply You just have to override **getAuthIdFromLocal()** method in **ChildViewController**

```
override func getAuthIdFromLocal() {
     super.getAuthIdFromLocal()
}
```

By calling **getAuthIdFromLocal()** in completion block of **fetchAuthIdFromServer()**, you will get new **authid** from local db.